# Unable to log into Amazon EC2 instance from MacBook Pro

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh

I'm trying to log into an EC2 instance I created on AWS with the following command:

sh -v -i MyEc2KeyPair2.pem ec2-user@54.146.40.216

After a while, I get a connection timed-out message:

```
# ssh -v -i MyEc2KeyPair2.pem ec2-user@54.146.40.216
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Connecting to 54.146.40.216 [54.146.40.216] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 54.146.40.216 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 54.146.40.216 port 22: Connection timed out
```

I've allowed all incoming for http, https, ssh and icmp. Although I allowed incoming pings on the server instance (icmp), a ping to the address just gets timeouts. A traceroute goes as far as the New York Comcast backbone, then starts showing asterisks. tcpdump with a grep on the address when I run the ssh shows only outgoing messages, with no incoming.

I also to ssh from a different server (a virtual host on bluehost), but got the same results. Obviously, I did a chmod 400 on the .pem as per Amazon instructions.

In case there was an error in the setup, I deleted and recreated the server, and am still having similar issues.

Any idea how to solve this? I'm stumped.

Edit: shown below are the input and outputs allowed per the security group:

[image: image which pops up when you press "view inbound rules]

[image: Inbound rules for the security group]

[image: Outbound rules for the security group]

Comment: Start by launching a new instance with a standard Amazon Linux AMI in the same subnet and with the security group, then try to connect. This will identify whether it is a connectivity issue or an issue with the instance. If you cannot connect, then check whether the instance was launched in a public subnet (defined as a subnet with a Route Table that points to an Internet Gateway).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've had no luck - I checked this morning and it's attached to an internet gateway. I have created 3 instances and haven't been able to connect to any of them.

Comment: Did you launch the instances in the Default VPC or a VPC you created yourself? What AMI did you select? What is the configuration of your Security Group? Try it from a different network (eg home vs work) in case the corporate network prohibits the connection.

Comment: It's the default VPC. I selected the Amazon Linux AM. The security group allows everything. I tried from home, and from a BlueHost server. When I get time, I'll try it from a pc. If you see this, can you try ping, ssh, and/or tracert on the IP address - 54.146.40.216? Thanks so much!

Comment: When attempting to connect, I also get a timeout. This is normally an indication that the Security Group is not permitting access on Port 22, or that the server is accepting connections on the port (which should not be the case if you used the Amazon Linux AMI). Please edit your question and include a screenshot of the Security Group. Have you got ANY EC2 instances that you can successfully access?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've posted the images. No, I have never gotten access on this account, which is a new one I just started recently.

Comment: So you can access EC2 instances on another account, just not this account? Can you try launching an instance in another region and see whether you can connect to it? That should help narrow-down the problem.

Comment: Hi John - well, I finally deleted that instance and started another one - my fourth instance, and ssh'd into it with no problem.  I have no idea what I did wrong on the first 3 tries. I didn't do anything different as far as I know, pretty much vanilla. Anyway, at least I have a clearer understanding of how the VPC and the subnets and security groups work. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to delete the instance and create another one.